# Meteor SimpleSchema says random stuff is valid

Tags: validation, meteor, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

I'm using `aldeed:collection2` and `aldeed:simple-schema` packages. I want to validate a doc against the schema. My schema contains e.g. a string field with allowedValues array and an array of nested object, described with sub-schema. Like this:

...

```
type: {
    type: String,
    allowedValues: [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ],
    defaultValue: 'A',
    index: 1,
  },
nestedStuff: {
    type: [ new SimpleSchema(nestedStuffSchema.schema(Meteor, SimpleSchema)) ],
    defaultValue: [],
  },
```

...

I have a 'bad' doc which has e.g. "D" in `type` field and invalid nested array items.

At client I'm trying to:

```
Contacts.simpleSchema().namedContext().validate(badDoc);
```

and it returns `true`. SimpleSchema says the doc is valid even though its fields do not abide to schema.
Validating 'bad' `type` field individually also returns `true`.
What am I doing wrong? Why could SimpleSchema assume random stuff to be valid?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to validate an array of strings you need to keep String inside [ ].See the below code it may help

```
type: {
     type: [String],
     allowedValues: [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ],
     defaultValue: ['A'],
     index: 1,
   },
nestedStuff: {
     type: [ new SimpleSchema(nestedStuffSchema.schema(Meteor,SimpleSchema)) ],
defaultValue: [],
  },
```

Thanks

Comment: would you be able to provide reference?